# How can I use python celery to consume a message with no task?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I need to consume a message from RabbitMQ, but the json string message does not include a task key, which I understand celery requires. Is there a way around this, perhaps with bootsteps? I.e., could I add a task to the message 'on the fly', or could I hard code / preset a task value?

You might be asking, "How do you know what function to call if there is no task provided?" For my use case, there is one and only one function that will be called by virtue of receiving a message in my queue.

Thank you!!